# Command not found when running function in bash

Tags: bash, shell-script, ubuntu, gnu-screen

I am trying to create a basic bash script that closes a screen and then starts a new one.

*restart.sh*

```
#!/bin/bash

set -o nounset
set -o errexit
trap 'echo "Aborting due to errexit on line $LINENO. Exit code: $?" >&2' ERR
set -o errtrace
set -o pipefail

SCR="bunny"
SCRIPT="/home/../run.sh" 

target_screen=$(find_screen $SCR)

main() {
    if find_screen $SCR >/dev/null; then
        close_screen
        start_script
    fi
}

function start_script {
    echo "Starting script with new screen"
    screen -d -m -t $SCR sh $SCRIPT
}

function close_screen {
    if find_screen $SCR >/dev/null; then
        echo "Found! Deleting $SCR"
        screen -S -X $target_screen quit
    fi
}

function find_screen {
    if screen -ls "$1" | grep -o "^\s*[0-9]*\.$1[ "$'\t'"](" --color=NEVER -m 1 | grep -oh "[0-9]*\.$1" --color=NEVER -m 1 -q >/dev/null; then
        screen -ls "$1" | grep -o "^\s*[0-9]*\.$1[ "$'\t'"](" --color=NEVER -m 1 | grep -oh "[0-9]*\.$1" --color=NEVER -m 1 2>/dev/null
        return 0
    else
        echo "$1"
        return 1
    fi
}

main "$@"
```

However when running this script on Ubuntu 16.04, I get the following:

```
    ./restart.sh: line 12: find_screen: command not found
Aborting due to errexit on line 12. Exit code: 127
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You're calling `target_screen=$(find_screen $SCR)` before the `find_screen` command has been defined.

Comment: Thanks. There are a few more problems now. When starting the screen, I get the black screen http://i.imgur.com/RCojPmK.png and for some reason, it not only restarts the bunny screen but also appends another screen with a weird name with two dots. Any ideas?

Comment: @kinx That's a new question. Consequently, you should post a new question!